# How to convert Shift-JIS encoded string to UTF-8?

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, sqlite, shift-jis

I am getting html source from [Aozora Bunko](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001095/files/42992_21280.html). Html file is Shift-JIS encoded. I am trying to get book title and author. Then I want to record title and author into SQLite(UTF-8) database.

```
    String[] splittedResult = result.split("\"title\">");
            splittedResult = splittedResult[1].split("</h1>");
            String title = splittedResult[0];
            byte[] b = null;
            try {
                b = title.getBytes("Shift_JIS");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String value=null;
            try {
                value = new String(b, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

...
myDatabase.addBookInformation(value, author);
```

Result is like this: latin letters are showing normally. But japanese letters are shown by blocks question mark inside (please do not pay attention to null values)

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: A Java byte array can contain a string with a specific encoding. A Java string cannot: it's basically an array of characters without involving any encoding. Your code starts with a string variable (named `result`). So the conversion from an HTML page with a specific encoding into a character array without encoding has already taken place. Use the debugger to check whether `result` or `title` contains proper Japanese characters. If not, the problem is before the code you show in the question. If it's okay, then I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @Codo pointed out, solution for this problem was before.
I changed this

```
s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

to this

```
s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "Shift_JIS");
```

And now there is no need for encoding.

```
String[] splittedResult = result.split("\"title\">");
        splittedResult = splittedResult[1].split("</h1>");
        String title = splittedResult[0];
        /** I HAVE TAKEN THIS PART OF MY CODE
        byte[] b = null;
        try {
            b = title.getBytes("Shift_JIS");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String value=null;
        try {
            value = new String(b, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        **/
```